# Non-standard file/directory found at top level error when adding a sound file in my package

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to make my first personal R package where I am passing few .wav files in my package like so:

```r
#....extra code
natural_noise <- "birdsound.wav"
wav_file_location <- system.file(paste("sound/", natural_noise, sep=""), package= "package1")
```

I have a the file birdsound.wav in a sound folder within the same R package project directory. But it is keep leading to error when I use the `Check` feature:
`checking top-level files ... NOTE
  Non-standard file/directory found at top level:
    'sound'`

When I delete my folder and move the wav file out of the folder, I get same error with but last line changes:
`checking top-level files ... NOTE
Non-standard file/directory found at top level:
birdsound.wav`

Can some one give me direction. I have looked at google and forums here already. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put extra files in the `inst` directory within the package. For a sound-specific example, see the structure of the [beepr package](https://github.com/rasmusab/beepr), which puts `.wav` files in `inst/sounds/`.

The [R Packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html) has a section with more deatails.